# How do I locally enqeue the mediaelement.js file into a wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development

I'm converting a HTML and CSS template into  a wordpress theme, When I open the HTMl and CSS file the audio player works normally as it should, but when I convert into a wordpress theme it doesn't work, I have tried to enqeue the mediaelement-and-player.min.js like this

```
function music_theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mep_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , '', true);
```

still nothing shows. Please Help!

[It shows up normal when opened through a normal HTML and CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9QfR.png)

[But breaks when I convert to a wordpress theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzwrc.png) 
Here is the wp_enqueue_script

```
<?php

function flexing_theme_styles() {

      /* theme's primary style.css file */
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css' , get_stylesheet_uri() );


  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );



}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'flexing_theme_styles' );


function flexing_theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jssor.slider_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jssor.slider-21.1.6.mini.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mediaelement_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js' , array( 'jquery' ) , '', true);

}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'flexing_theme_js' );

?>
```

Comment: Some questions: Does the file get included on the frontend? ( Look at the source, even if the file's included but doesn't do anything it's still necessary info ). Are there errors in your browser dev tools console? Do you hook the `music_theme_js` function on to the right hook? ( that part of your code is missing in your question, along with the rest of the `music_theme_js` function ). Finally, when you say nothing shows, do you mean that the audio player doesn't show, or that nothing at all shows and it's a blank white page? Please update your question with the answer to *all* these questions

Comment: Yes the files are included on the frontend, It shows up when I view the page source, I used <?php wp_footer(); ?> to include the js files in the footer. The audio player is picking up the styles when I convert it to a wordpress theme, but displays the default browser player. I will update my questionwith pictures. Thank you.

Comment: Give us your enqueue code. I mean where you have called `wp_enqueue_script`, the full block of code. @Jay

Comment: @ the_dramatist I updated the question.

Comment: On which file you've put the initiation code of `MediaElement.js` ? @Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init the `MediaElement.js` by doing-

For video or audio tag-

```
<script>
// using jQuery
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
</script>
```

And for custom `div`-

```
<script>
// JavaScript object for later use
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',/* Options */);
// ... more code ...
player.pause();
player.setSrc('mynewfile.mp4');
player.play();
</script>
```

Just have a look on [`MediaElement.js`](http://mediaelementjs.com/) wesite.

And it would be better to write the `main_js` enqueue line like below-

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js' , array( 'mediaelement_js', 'jquery' ) , '', true);
```

Cause as far as I understood you've put you custom JavaScript code in this file. So better enqueue it after `MediaElement.js`.

And in your HTML file it is working cause I think they have called it in HTML file inside `<script></script>` tag. And in your theme it is not working cause the init of `MediaElement.js` is happening before the `MediaElement.js` is loaded. So better move this code to you custom script file (like `main.js`) and call it after `MediaElement.js`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I moved the init file into main.js, it still wasn't working had to Disable cache then refreshed to get it right. Thanks alot @ the_dramatist.